# Challenge with Google Classroom Integration: App Verification and Sensitive Scopes

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-classroom, scopes

We are currently in the process of integrating classrooms into our website. However, we have encountered an error during this integration. When the app is in production, we receive an error message stating, `"This app is blocked - This app tried to access sensitive information in your Google Account, and to keep your account safe, Google has blocked this access."` Additionally, in the testing mode, we encounter the error `"Access blocked: the app has not completed the Google verification process, Error 403: access_denied."` These errors arise due to the sensitive scopes included in our implementation of Google Sign-In for the classroom.

To proceed with the verification process and address these errors, we are required to submit an app verification video to Google. This video will demonstrate how we utilize these scopes on our website. However, the challenge we currently face is that without a successful login using the scopes, it becomes difficult to showcase their specific use.

We made an effort to submit a video to Google showcasing the process of importing classrooms on our website. However, Google requires the video to illustrate how our project specifically utilizes the requested scopes. We have created OAuth 2.0 client ID.

To enhance user experience on our website, it is crucial for us to utilize the requested scopes, which allow for seamless access to the classroom functionality. These scopes play a vital role in ensuring that users can conveniently navigate and engage with the classroom feature on our platform.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident to say that the error message you are seeing should not happen if you are trying to run the code from the account that created it, as such I would advise you to either

1. Try running the code yourself directly from apps script to showcase what it should do or
2. If the code should only work if you have a specific scenario you currently do not meet (i.e. having a class of at least 50 members) try asking someone else that meets that criteria to copy the code and run it from their user

There is also a possible workaround if you have a Google Workspace account as you can [Let internal apps access restricted Google Workspace APIs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en#zippy=%2Cselect-settings-for-unconfigured-apps:%7E:text=Let%20internal%20apps%20access%20restricted%20Google%20Workspace%20APIs), I have not been able to test this myself but it sounds like that would do the trick here.

Comment: the account was created with the client's credentials, and during the initial development time, we used our emails during testing. So our accounts and some external testers' accounts were used for testing. Is there any way to reset the OAuth user cap or check the list of emails under test cap?

Comment: I believe you can follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent#configure_oauth_consent_register_your_app) to review the users, I'm not sure if that will allow you to remove users though... please let me know how it goes!